# Y we have convert image pixel values to freq domain by using dct

Tags: image, compression

Image compression using dct.by using dct we convert real points to real spectrum. Y we have to convert?

Answer (score 0):

We separate the image data into different frequencies, because the human eye is much less sensitive to high frequencies than low ones.  This lets us record the high frequency data *much less accurately*, which means spending fewer bits on it.

This is the most important mechanism by which compression is achieved in JPEG, etc.